# Is the Microsoft Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block thread safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, enterprise-library, daab

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding thread safety...

In particular - is the `Database` class (and subclasses) thread safe

How would I find this out for myself? Are there references to thread safety for classes on the MSDN site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instances of the `Database` class are thread-safe. However, objects created by it (such as `SqlDataReader`) are not.

Comment: How would I go about making the objects created by the Database class thread safe? For instance, if I use the database class to create the command object (GetSqlStringCommand) how do I ensure thread safety on this object?